# DevOps solution for Android Studio updates

Tags: android-studio, devops

we have a large team of developers using Android Studio for developing Android Apps. Problem that we face is:

For each new update, each developer updates through the Android Studio's Update Manager. Due to update sizes in x100 MBs or even GBs, it quickly adds up for so many developers. Is there a way to mirror the Android Studio update, so that we have one machine which updates the normal way (from Internet) and others do so over LAN from this machine? From DevOps PoV, it would help me maintain same version of Android Studio and its components on all machines.